# SQL Server Query: Inefficient where clause

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have the following SQL query:

```
select *
from NETWORK n
inner join vwNETWORK_KEYMSTN km on n.Network_ID = km.Network_ID
inner join vwAPPROVAL_LATEST a on n.Network_ID = a.Network_ID
inner join APPROVAL_VINTAGE av on a.Approval_ID = av.Approval_ID and km.Milestone_Type_ID = av.Milestone_Type_ID
inner join NETWORK_MILESTONE m on A.Approval_ID = m.Approval_ID and km.Milestone_Type_ID = m.Milestone_Type_ID
inner join REF_MILESTONE rm on km.Milestone_Type_ID = rm.Milestone_Type_ID
inner join NETWORK_STATUS s on n.Network_ID = s.Network_ID --and s.Status_Type_ID = 2
--where rm.Status_Type_ID = s.Status_Type_ID
```

This query returns in about 6s. The last table, NETWORK_STATUS, causes my result set to split out. That is, n.Network_ID would be unique before adding that last table NETWORK_STATUS to the join.

Adding the join clause that is currently commented out will return a unique set of Network_ID again. The commented out join will a result set in fast time, ie, < 10s.

However, what I truly want is the where clause that is commented out, or I could put it as part of the join. A MILESTONE_type is associated with only one STATUS_type. Putting this part in, which is seemingly a trivial addition to the query, causes a massive explosion in run time... I kill the query after a minute, but it could be even greater than a 6x factor increase in run time.

My question to this forum is why that might be the case, and more importantly, how do I tell SQL Server that this really isn't a hard where clause to execute. At most, the where clause should return in < 20s... it could return the full set with duplicates (~6s), and then 2nd pass simply trim out the rows that don't satisfy the where clause.

Execution Plan:
here is the problem line:

```
--Index Scan(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[IX_NETWORK_STATUS_Status_Type_ID] AS [s]),  WHERE:(PROBE([Opt_Bitmap1070],[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Status_Type_ID] as [s].[Status_Type_ID],N'[IN ROW]')))
```

Here is the full execution plan:

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1029]=CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[Milestone_DT] as [m1].[Milestone_DT]<>(-1) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [cprd].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN isnull([Expr1015],($0.0000))>=isnull([Expr1016],($0.0000)) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [fcom].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[Network_NM] as [n].[Network_NM] like '%:EQ%' OR [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[Network_NM] as [n].[Network_NM] like '%:IP' THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [fcom].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN isnull([Expr1015],($0.0000))<isnull([Expr1016],($0.0000)) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [nisr].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [unknown].[Milestone_Type_ID] END END END END))
       |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
            |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:(CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[Milestone_DT] as [m1].[Milestone_DT]<>(-1) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [cprd].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN isnull([Expr1015],($0.0000))>=isnull([Expr1016],($0.0000)) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [fcom].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[Network_NM] as [n].[Network_NM] like '%:EQ%' OR [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[Network_NM] as [n].[Network_NM] like '%:IP' THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [fcom].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN isnull([Expr1015],($0.0000))<isnull([Expr1016],($0.0000)) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [nisr].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [unknown].[Milestone_Type_ID] END END END END=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [rm].[Milestone_Type_ID] AND CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[Milestone_DT] as [m1].[Milestone_DT]<>(-1) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [cprd].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN isnull([Expr1015],($0.0000))>=isnull([Expr1016],($0.0000)) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [fcom].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[Network_NM] as [n].[Network_NM] like '%:EQ%' OR [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[Network_NM] as [n].[Network_NM] like '%:IP' THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [fcom].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN isnull([Expr1015],($0.0000))<isnull([Expr1016],($0.0000)) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [nisr].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [unknown].[Milestone_Type_ID] END END END END=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [m].[Milestone_Type_ID] AND CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[Milestone_DT] as [m1].[Milestone_DT]<>(-1) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [cprd].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN isnull([Expr1015],($0.0000))>=isnull([Expr1016],($0.0000)) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [fcom].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[Network_NM] as [n].[Network_NM] like '%:EQ%' OR [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[Network_NM] as [n].[Network_NM] like '%:IP' THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [fcom].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE CASE WHEN isnull([Expr1015],($0.0000))<isnull([Expr1016],($0.0000)) THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [nisr].[Milestone_Type_ID] ELSE [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [unknown].[Milestone_Type_ID] END END END END=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[APPROVAL_VINTAGE].[Milestone_Type_ID] as [av].[Milestone_Type_ID]))
                 |--Nested Loops(Inner Join)
                 |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join)
                 |    |    |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([cprd].[Milestone_Type_ID])=([m1].[Milestone_Type_ID]))
                 |    |    |    |--Parallelism(Distribute Streams, Broadcast Partitioning)
                 |    |    |    |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[PK_REF_NETWORK_MILESTONE] AS [cprd]), WHERE:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_NM] as [cprd].[Milestone_NM]='CPRD'))
                 |    |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([m1].[Milestone_ID], [Expr1078]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
                 |    |    |         |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([b].[Approval_ID], [Expr1077]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
                 |    |    |         |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([m].[Milestone_ID], [Expr1076]) WITH ORDERED PREFETCH)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([b].[Approval_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([b].[Approval_ID] ASC))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Expr1008], [ra].[Approval_Type_ID], [s].[Network_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([b].[Approval_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([a].[Approval_Type_ID], [Expr1034], [s].[Network_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([s].[Network_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([s].[Network_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([a].[Approval_Type_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([s].[Network_Status_ID], [rm].[Milestone_Type_ID], [a].[Approval_Type_ID], [a].[Approval_Type_ID]) DEFINE:([Expr1008]=MAX([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[Approval_Version_NUM] as [a].[Approval_Version_NUM]), [Expr1015]=ANY([Expr1015]), [Expr1016]=ANY([Expr1016]), [Expr1034]=ANY([Expr1034]), [rm].[Milestone_NM]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_NM] as [rm].[Milestone_NM]), [rm].[Status_Type_ID]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Status_Type_ID] as [rm].[Status_Type_ID]), [s].[Network_ID]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_ID] as [s].[Network_ID]), [s].[Status_Type_ID]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Status_Type_ID] as [rm].[Status_Type_ID]), [s].[Status_DT]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Status_DT] as [s].[Status_DT]), [s].[Current_IND]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Current_IND] as [s].[Current_IND])))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([s].[Network_Status_ID] ASC, [rm].[Milestone_Type_ID] ASC, [a].[Approval_Type_ID] ASC, [a].[Approval_Type_ID] ASC))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |         |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([s].[Network_Status_ID], [rm].[Milestone_Type_ID], [a].[Approval_Type_ID], [a].[Approval_Type_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |              |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([s].[Network_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([s].[Network_Status_ID], [rm].[Milestone_Type_ID], [a].[Approval_Type_ID]) DEFINE:([Expr1034]=MAX([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[Approval_Version_NUM] as [a].[Approval_Version_NUM]), [Expr1015]=ANY([Expr1015]), [Expr1016]=ANY([Expr1016]), [rm].[Milestone_NM]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_NM] as [rm].[Milestone_NM]), [rm].[Status_Type_ID]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Status_Type_ID] as [rm].[Status_Type_ID]), [s].[Network_ID]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_ID] as [s].[Network_ID]), [s].[Status_Type_ID]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Status_Type_ID] as [rm].[Status_Type_ID]), [s].[Status_DT]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Status_DT] as [s].[Status_DT]), [s].[Current_IND]=ANY([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Current_IND] as [s].[Current_IND])))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([s].[Network_Status_ID] ASC, [rm].[Milestone_Type_ID] ASC, [a].[Approval_Type_ID] ASC))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |         |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([s].[Network_Status_ID], [rm].[Milestone_Type_ID], [a].[Approval_Type_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |              |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([s].[Network_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([s].[Network_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |    |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([rm].[Status_Type_ID])=([s].[Status_Type_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |    |    |--Bitmap(HASH:([rm].[Status_Type_ID]), DEFINE:([Opt_Bitmap1070]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |    |    |    |--Parallelism(Distribute Streams, Broadcast Partitioning)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |    |    |         |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[PK_REF_NETWORK_MILESTONE] AS [rm]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([s].[Network_Status_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |    |         |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, RoundRobin Partitioning)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |    |         |    |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[IX_NETWORK_STATUS_Status_Type_ID] AS [s]),  WHERE:(PROBE([Opt_Bitmap1070],[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Status_Type_ID] as [s].[Status_Type_ID],N'[IN ROW]')))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |    |         |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[PK_NETWORK_STATUS] AS [s]), SEEK:([s].[Network_Status_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_Status_ID] as [s].[Network_Status_ID]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |    |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1015]=CASE WHEN [Expr1072]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1073] END, [Expr1016]=CASE WHEN [Expr1074]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1075] END))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |         |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1072]=COUNT_BIG(CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_CEGROUP].[CEGroup_NM] as [ret].[CEGroup_NM] like '3_IP%' OR [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_CEGROUP].[CEGroup_NM] as [ret].[CEGroup_NM] like '3_Ot%' THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_EXPENSE].[Expense_AMT] as [e].[Expense_AMT] ELSE NULL END), [Expr1073]=SUM(CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_CEGROUP].[CEGroup_NM] as [ret].[CEGroup_NM] like '3_IP%' OR [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_CEGROUP].[CEGroup_NM] as [ret].[CEGroup_NM] like '3_Ot%' THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_EXPENSE].[Expense_AMT] as [e].[Expense_AMT] ELSE NULL END), [Expr1074]=COUNT_BIG(CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_CEGROUP].[CEGroup_NM] as [ret].[CEGroup_NM] like '3_OP%' THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_EXPENSE].[Expense_AMT] as [e].[Expense_AMT] ELSE NULL END), [Expr1075]=SUM(CASE WHEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_CEGROUP].[CEGroup_NM] as [ret].[CEGroup_NM] like '3_OP%' THEN [CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_EXPENSE].[Expense_AMT] as [e].[Expense_AMT] ELSE NULL END)))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |              |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([e].[CEGroup_Type_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |                   |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([e].[Network_Expense_ID]))
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |                   |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_EXPENSE].[IX_NETWORK_EXPENSE_NETWORK_ID] AS [e]), SEEK:([e].[Network_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_ID] as [s].[Network_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |                   |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_EXPENSE].[PK_NetworkSpend] AS [e]), SEEK:([e].[Network_Expense_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_EXPENSE].[Network_Expense_ID] as [e].[Network_Expense_ID]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |                   |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_CEGROUP].[PK_REF_CEGrp] AS [ret]), SEEK:([ret].[CEGroup_Type_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_EXPENSE].[CEGroup_Type_ID] as [e].[CEGroup_Type_ID]),  WHERE:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_CEGROUP].[CEGroup_NM] as [ret].[CEGroup_NM] like '3%') ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |                   |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[IX_NETWORK_APPROVAL] AS [a]), SEEK:([a].[Network_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_ID] as [s].[Network_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |                   |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[IX_NETWORK_APPROVAL] AS [a]), SEEK:([a].[Network_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_ID] as [s].[Network_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_NTWK_APPROVAL_STATUS].[PK_REF_MILESTONE_VERSION] AS [ra]), SEEK:([ra].[Approval_Type_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[Approval_Type_ID] as [a].[Approval_Type_ID]),  WHERE:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_NTWK_APPROVAL_STATUS].[Approval_NM] as [ra].[Approval_NM]='LNA') ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[PK_DimNetwork] AS [n]), SEEK:([n].[Network_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_ID] as [s].[Network_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK].[PK_DimNetwork] AS [n]), SEEK:([n].[Network_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_ID] as [s].[Network_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[IX_NETWORK_APPROVAL] AS [b]), SEEK:([b].[Network_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_ID] as [s].[Network_ID] AND [b].[Approval_Type_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[Approval_Type_ID] as [a].[Approval_Type_ID] AND [b].[Approval_Version_NUM]=[Expr1034]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[APPROVAL_VINTAGE].[IX_APPROVAL_VINTAGE] AS [av]), SEEK:([av].[Approval_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[Approval_ID] as [b].[Approval_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |         |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[IX_NETWORK_APPROVAL] AS [b]), SEEK:([b].[Network_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_STATUS].[Network_ID] as [s].[Network_ID] AND [b].[Approval_Type_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_NTWK_APPROVAL_STATUS].[Approval_Type_ID] as [ra].[Approval_Type_ID] AND [b].[Approval_Version_NUM]=[Expr1008]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[IX_NETWORK_MILESTONE] AS [m]), SEEK:([m].[Approval_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[Approval_ID] as [b].[Approval_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |    |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[PK_MILESTONE] AS [m]), SEEK:([m].[Milestone_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[Milestone_ID] as [m].[Milestone_ID]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[IX_NETWORK_MILESTONE] AS [m1]), SEEK:([m1].[Approval_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_APPROVAL].[Approval_ID] as [b].[Approval_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |         |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[PK_MILESTONE] AS [m1]), SEEK:([m1].[Milestone_ID]=[CSDConstruction].[dbo].[NETWORK_MILESTONE].[Milestone_ID] as [m1].[Milestone_ID]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
                 |    |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[PK_REF_NETWORK_MILESTONE] AS [nisr]), WHERE:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_NM] as [nisr].[Milestone_NM]='NISR'))
                 |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[PK_REF_NETWORK_MILESTONE] AS [unknown]), WHERE:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_NM] as [unknown].[Milestone_NM]='UNKNOWN'))
                 |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[PK_REF_NETWORK_MILESTONE] AS [fcom]), WHERE:([CSDConstruction].[dbo].[REF_MILESTONE].[Milestone_NM] as [fcom].[Milestone_NM]='FCOM'))
```

Here is what the data looks like:

```
Network_ID  Network_NUM Network_NM  Network_ID  Milestone_Type_ID   Approval_ID Network_ID  Approval_Type_ID    Approval_Version_NUM    Approval_Vintage_ID Approval_ID Milestone_Type_ID   Milestone_ID    Approval_ID Milestone_Type_ID   Milestone_DT    Milestone_Type_ID   Milestone_NM    Status_Type_ID  Network_Status_ID   Network_ID  Status_Type_ID  Status_DT   Current_IND
613693  2027581 GCC:CYPS:FEEDER FROM NEW GLENAYRE HUB   613693  6   716823  613693  1   2   85707   716823  6   2493490 716823  6   20080229    6   NISR    6   352472  613693  1   20010307    0
613693  2027581 GCC:CYPS:FEEDER FROM NEW GLENAYRE HUB   613693  6   716823  613693  1   2   85707   716823  6   2493490 716823  6   20080229    6   NISR    6   633324  613693  2   20010614    0
613693  2027581 GCC:CYPS:FEEDER FROM NEW GLENAYRE HUB   613693  6   716823  613693  1   2   85707   716823  6   2493490 716823  6   20080229    6   NISR    6   948846  613693  3   20030924    0
613693  2027581 GCC:CYPS:FEEDER FROM NEW GLENAYRE HUB   613693  6   716823  613693  1   2   85707   716823  6   2493490 716823  6   20080229    6   NISR    6   1264368 613693  4   20031007    0
613693  2027581 GCC:CYPS:FEEDER FROM NEW GLENAYRE HUB   613693  6   716823  613693  1   2   85707   716823  6   2493490 716823  6   20080229    6   NISR    6   1579890 613693  5   20090515    0
613693  2027581 GCC:CYPS:FEEDER FROM NEW GLENAYRE HUB   613693  6   716823  613693  1   2   85707   716823  6   2493490 716823  6   20080229    6   NISR    6   1895412 613693  6   20090515    0
613693  2027581 GCC:CYPS:FEEDER FROM NEW GLENAYRE HUB   613693  6   716823  613693  1   2   85707   716823  6   2493490 716823  6   20080229    6   NISR    6   2210934 613693  7   20100526    0
613693  2027581 GCC:CYPS:FEEDER FROM NEW GLENAYRE HUB   613693  6   716823  613693  1   2   85707   716823  6   2493490 716823  6   20080229    6   NISR    6   2526456 613693  8   20100901    0
618637  2114067 BJK:RCMD:8120 LANSDOWNE RD 256 UNIT HIGH    618637  6   720878  618637  1   2   92712   720878  6   2497545 720878  6   20090327    6   NISR    6   457111  618637  1   20031020    0
618637  2114067 BJK:RCMD:8120 LANSDOWNE RD 256 UNIT HIGH    618637  6   720878  618637  1   2   92712   720878  6   2497545 720878  6   20090327    6   NISR    6   637149  618637  2   20031027    0
618637  2114067 BJK:RCMD:8120 LANSDOWNE RD 256 UNIT HIGH    618637  6   720878  618637  1   2   92712   720878  6   2497545 720878  6   20090327    6   NISR    6   952671  618637  3   20081210    0
618637  2114067 BJK:RCMD:8120 LANSDOWNE RD 256 UNIT HIGH    618637  6   720878  618637  1   2   92712   720878  6   2497545 720878  6   20090327    6   NISR    6   1268193 618637  4   20090811    0
618637  2114067 BJK:RCMD:8120 LANSDOWNE RD 256 UNIT HIGH    618637  6   720878  618637  1   2   92712   720878  6   2497545 720878  6   20090327    6   NISR    6   1583715 618637  5   20090911    0
618637  2114067 BJK:RCMD:8120 LANSDOWNE RD 256 UNIT HIGH    618637  6   720878  618637  1   2   92712   720878  6   2497545 720878  6   20090327    6   NISR    6   1899237 618637  6   20090911    0
618637  2114067 BJK:RCMD:8120 LANSDOWNE RD 256 UNIT HIGH    618637  6   720878  618637  1   2   92712   720878  6   2497545 720878  6   20090327    6   NISR    6   2214759 618637  7   20100305    0
618637  2114067 BJK:RCMD:8120 LANSDOWNE RD 256 UNIT HIGH    618637  6   720878  618637  1   2   92712   720878  6   2497545 720878  6   20090327    6   NISR    6   2530281 618637  8   20100701    0
621017  2135192 RAD:NWTN:8 LOT SUBD EDINBURGH DR N/O 88 621017  6   555884  621017  1   3   71742   555884  6   2332551 555884  6   20091127    6   NISR    6   542606  621017  1   20040525    0
621017  2135192 RAD:NWTN:8 LOT SUBD EDINBURGH DR N/O 88 621017  6   555884  621017  1   3   71742   555884  6   2332551 555884  6   20091127    6   NISR    6   639371  621017  2   20040525    0
621017  2135192 RAD:NWTN:8 LOT SUBD EDINBURGH DR N/O 88 621017  6   555884  621017  1   3   71742   555884  6   2332551 555884  6   20091127    6   NISR    6   954893  621017  3   20091020    0
621017  2135192 RAD:NWTN:8 LOT SUBD EDINBURGH DR N/O 88 621017  6   555884  621017  1   3   71742   555884  6   2332551 555884  6   20091127    6   NISR    6   1270415 621017  4   20091020    0
```

Trying to select the subset where the 3rd and 6th columns *from the end* match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need the other data from the NETWORK_STATUS table, how about:

```
select *
from dbo.NETWORK AS n
inner join dbo.vwNETWORK_KEYMSTN AS km 
  on n.Network_ID = km.Network_ID
inner join dbo.vwAPPROVAL_LATEST AS a 
  on n.Network_ID = a.Network_ID
inner join dbo.APPROVAL_VINTAGE  AS av 
  on a.Approval_ID = av.Approval_ID 
  and km.Milestone_Type_ID = av.Milestone_Type_ID
inner join dbo.NETWORK_MILESTONE AS m 
  on A.Approval_ID = m.Approval_ID 
  and km.Milestone_Type_ID = m.Milestone_Type_ID
inner join dbo.REF_MILESTONE AS rm 
  on km.Milestone_Type_ID = rm.Milestone_Type_ID
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.NETWORK_STATUS 
    WHERE Network_ID = n.Network_ID
    and Status_Type_ID = 2
    --and Status_Type_ID = rm.Status_Type_ID
);
```